# Time complexity of my solution to finding the longest common prefix of an array of strings

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

I wrote a solution for this following problem:

```
Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.

If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".
```

Can someone help me break down the time complexity of my code? I sorted the array first which makes the time complexity O(n log n). Then I am looping through the length of the shortest element in the input array (would this be considered O(n), and then lastly another while loop through the length of the input array. So my guess is overall time complexity of O(n^2)? If so, is it possible to optimize my code to make it even faster? Thanks!

```
class Solution:
    def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
        strs.sort(key=len)
        longestPrefix = ""
        index = 1
        char = 0
        skip = False
        
        if not strs:
            return ""
        
        for _ in range(len(strs[0])):
            while index < len(strs):
                if strs[0][char] ==  strs[index][char]:
                    index += 1
                else:
                    skip = True
                    break
            if not skip:
                longestPrefix += strs[0][char]
                char += 1
                index = 1
            else:
                break
        
        return longestPrefix
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution can be achieve in O(n*log n* max_str_len), where n is the number of strings and max_str_len is the maximum strings' length.
You don't need to check every string in your list, just the first and the last.
I changed a few your code:

```
def longestCommonPrefix(strs) -> str:

len_list = len(strs)
if (len_list == 0): 
    return "" 

if (len_list == 1): 
    return strs[0] 
strs.sort()
longestPrefix = ""
# retrieving the minimum length of the first and last element of the list
min_word_len = min(len(strs[0]), len(strs[len_list - 1])) 

# looking for the common prefix between the first and last string  
i = 0
while (i < min_word_len and strs[0][i] == strs[len_list - 1][i]): 
    i += 1
    
longestPrefix = strs[0][0: i] 
return longestPrefix
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the zip function to go through the strings in parallel, you should get a performance of O(N*M) where N is the number of strings and M is the shortest size (or length of common prefix).

```
from itertools import takewhile
def commonPrefix(*strings):
    return "".join(c for c,*_ in
                   takewhile(lambda c:all(s==c[0] for s in c),zip(*strings)))

commonPrefix("abcde","abddes","abegh") # "ab"
```